# S0/0 and S0/1 overlapping Error

Tags: router

I have three routers connected with the middle router having s0/0 and s0/1 as its ports. Consider them to be R1, R2,R3. R2 being the router in the middle. R1 uses s0/0 and is connected to s0/0 of R2. S0/1 of R2 is connected connect to s0/1 of R3. However when I am configuring interface S0/1 it gives me this error " 201.195.144.0 overlaps with Serial0/0".

R2- S0/0-201.195.144.1(DCE)

R2-S0/1-201.195.144.5(DCE)

R1-S0/0-201.195.144.2(DTE)

R3-S0/1-201.195.144.6(DTE)

Can anyone suggest as to what needs to be done. I have tried to do it multiple times and it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your addresses, you need to use masks of `255.255.255.252`. If you use subnets any larger, you will overlap the subnets, and you can't do that on the router interfaces.

Comment: Hi Ron. I used the subnet mask as 255.255.255.0 for configuring all the interfaces. Is this the correct way? I have tried to do the 255.255.255.252 but it did not work

Comment: If these are point-to-point links you can use `255.255.255.252` (`/30`) with the addresses you have, but you need to use it on both sides of the links (all four interface which are involved). Using `255.255.255.0` makes both links in the same subnet, and you can't do that with router ports. If using `/30` doesn't work, you are doing something else wrong. You didn't include the configurations, so we can only guess.